# Is it possible to set quality with Timber's towebp filter?

Tags: timber

As the title says. I'm using Timber's built-in filter to convert images to webp, like so:

`<img src="{{ image.url|towebp }}">`

It looks like the [default is 80](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/master/lib/ImageHelper.php#L216). Is it possible to change this site-wide, or within the `towebp` filter, something like this:

`<img src="{{ image.url|towebp(100) }}">`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are correct, this piece is correct solution. I made some debug and it passes 100 to quality parameter of the filter.

`<img src="{{ image.url|towebp(100) }}">`